# overloading operator. Const arguments make some problems

Tags: c++

```
class Vector{
......
.......
private:
int dim;
public:
int getDim() {
return this->dim;


}
const Vector operator+(const  Vector& right){
this->getSize();
}
 };
```

And I got compile error in this->getSize();. It is caused fact, that argument right is const. I don't know where is problem. I don't try modify right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably you have a non-const method `Vector::getSize()`. You need to make it `const` so that it can be called on `const` objects or via `const` references or pointers to `const`. For example:

```
int getSize() const;
              ^^^^^
```

Also note that it doesn't make much sense to return a `const` value (and would inhibit move semantics if you had them). The canonical form of an addition member operator would be

```
// const method: A = B + C should not modify B
Vector operator+(const Vector& right) const;
                                      ^^^^^
```

and the non-member

```
Vector operator+(const Vector& left, const Vector& right);
```